# Make elements align vertically in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The problem is that if I put an `h1` in the document, it takes up the page until the footer. Without flexbox this will not happen. It's like if the title occupies one column and the paragraph another one. The `h1` must align above the paragraph.

https://jsfiddle.net/45j2yrzp/

```css
html {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
/* IE fix */

body {
  display: flex;
  /* crée un contexte flex pour ses enfants */
  flex-direction: column;
  /* affichage vertical */
  min-height: 100vh;
  /* toute la hauteur du viewport (compatible IE9+) */
  font-family: cursive, sans-serif, serif;
}
.wrapper {
  display: block;
  /* IE fix */
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  /* occupe la hauteur restante */
  display: flex;
  /* crée un contexte flex pour ses enfants */
  flex-direction: row;
  /* affichage horizontal */
}
.content {
  display: flex;
  /* IE fix */
  flex: 1;
  /* occupe la largeur restante */
}
aside {
  position: fixed;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  top: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #cecece;
}
.left {
  left: 10%;
}
.right {
  right: 10%;
}
.arrow_left {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 25px solid #cecece;
  top: 20%;
  left: 25%;
}
.arrow_right {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  border-left: 25px solid #cecece;
  top: 20%;
  left: 40%;
}
aside:hover {
  border-color: #ff5722;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.80);
}
.left:hover .arrow_left {
  border-right-color: #ff5722;
}
.right:hover .arrow_right {
  border-left-color: #ff5722;
}
/* Decoration */

body {
  background: #eeeeee;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}
footer {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #303030;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.99);
  color: white;
}
section {
  margin: 45px 20% 0px 20%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40);
  overflow: hidden;
}
ul.menu {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  top: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.99);
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #303030;
  color: white;
}
li a {
  float: left;
  padding: 13px 16px;
  text-align: center;
}
li a:hover {
  background-color: #ff5722;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.80);
}
#home {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
li.active {
  background-color: #ff5722;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.99);
}
li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
}
address {
  margin-top: 3px;
}
/*End of the structure of the page*/

a {
  color: #ff5722;
  text-decoration: none;
}
span {
  color: #ff5722;
}
p {
  word-break: break-all;
  margin: 15px 30px;
}
img {
  height: 75%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="">Option 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Option 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Option 3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Option 4</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Option 5</a>
    </li>
    <li class="active"><a href="">Option 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Option 1</a>
    </li>
    <li id="home"><a href="index.html">Home</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</header>

<div class="wrapper">
  <section class="content">
    <h1>HELLO THIS IS THE TITLE</h1>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p>hello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello
      this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this
      is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is
      the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the
      paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello
      this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this
      is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is
      the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the
      paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello
      this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this
      is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is
      the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the
      paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello
      this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this
      is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is
      the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the
      paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello
      this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this is the paragraphhello this
      is the paragraphhello this is the paragraph</p>
  </section>
  <aside class="left">
    <div class="arrow_left"></div>
  </aside>
  <aside class="right">
    <div class="arrow_right"></div>
  </aside>
</div>
<!-- /wrapper -->

<footer>
  <address>Name Surname<br><a href="mailto:email@gmail.com">email@gmail.com</a></address>
</footer>
```

Comment: I don't believe there's any reason you'd want a flexbox. All the items are block elements by default and giving the wrapper `display: flex` and `flex-direction: column` doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An initial setting of a flex container is [`flex-direction: row`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-direction-property).

This aligns child elements (flex items) horizontally.

That's why your `h1` and paragraph are lined up in a row.

To achieve the layout you want, add this to your code:

```
.content { flex-direction: column; }
```

You already have `flex-direction: column` on an ancestor element (`body`).

However, a [***flex formatting context***](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-containers) is limited in scope to a parent / child relationship. Descendants beyond the children will not accept flex properties from an ancestor.

You will always need to apply `display: flex` or `display: inline-flex` to parent elements in order for flex properties to work on the children.